# Geometry Dash Create Account: Email is Invalid

Tags: geometry-dash

I'm trying to create an account on Geometry Dash but it keeps saying "email is invalid" even though I have tried 3 different completely valid emails.

Anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: A valid email must have an @ symbol in it, follow by the domain of a valid website. Such as outlook.com, or btinternet.co.uk you should also check for spelling errors in the email address.

Comment: If you get the "username taken" message, you can't try again with the same email address. If you're using Gmail, you can create a "new" username by putting one or more '.' before the '@'. The email will look different to Geometry Dash, but will go to your email.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the app to create an account. For some reason, if you put your e-mail in once but have a taken username, it won't allow you to enter that same email again. Go the help page in the account option and it should take you to a login/register site.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting that error message, you can enter your email at http://www.boomlings.com/database/accounts/invalidEmail.php and it will be fixed.

Comment: Isn't boomlings a different game? Same original creator but I heard RobTop got rid of it/is no longer supporting it.

Comment: @roddy: Boomlings is from the same creator, RobTop Games.

Comment: I liked this answer because it might get someone closer to a solution. However, in my case, using that page didn't help. All in all, this is a bizarre problem with bad UX.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the comment ... "same original creator, no longer supporting it". -_-

Answer (score 1):

You can try to troubleshoot it by yourself.

Assuming that your mail wording is right:

1)**Turn off and back on the device.** Try to input the mail again. If the problem is still there then:

2)**Turn off and back on the internet connection then try again.** Still not working?

3)**Create a new mail and try that.** If that is still not enough just:

4)**Delete the game and download it again.** It shouldn't be a problem since it's a pretty small game.

If the problem persists after every step just contact the Game Support for Geometry Dash, describing your issue and the steps you did to try to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score -1):

I've been getting the same problem. I think you should free up your space so you can try again. Delete some apps including geometry dash and pictures. After you think you freed up enough re download geometry dash and try again.